# How can I hardcode template selection?

Tags: templates

I'm trying to adapt Codex '[template include](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include)' for multiple conditional instances.

I'm using this...

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'set_templates', 99 );

function set_templates( $template ) {

if ( is_page( 'example_1' )  ) {
$new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-1.php' ) );
}

elseif ( is_page( 'example_2' )  ) {
$new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-2.php' ) );
}

elseif ( is_single( 'example_3' )  ) {
$new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-3.php' ) );
}

if ( '' != $new_template ) {
return $new_template ;
}

return $template;
}
```

It works - but I don't know enough to be sure about what I'm doing. (I realise this is more of a php than WP-specific question.

And what does 'if ( '' != $new_template )' mean?

Comment: This looks correct. The last conditional makes sure that the specified file was actually found - if that file was missing or you typed it wrong, it won't override it with a nonexistent template.

Comment: The `!` negates. true becomes false, and anything that evaluated to false becomes true.

Comment: Thanks to you both for clarifying. (And I'm sorry for my slow reply.)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's take a look at your code with some comments to show what's happening.

```
/**
 * Adds the function "set_templates" to the "template_include" filter with a
 * prioritiy of 99 (default is 10).
 *
 * What this means is that whenever WordPress runs the filter "template_link",
 * your function "set_templates" will be called and the value that is about to
 * be returned for "template_link" could be modified by your code.
 *
 * In WordPress, this fitler gets called in wp-includes/template-loader.php 
 * after WordPress does all of it's internal "magic" to figure out which template
 * to use.
 *
 * The priority of 99 tells WordPress to run the filter later than most other
 * filter functions, meaning yours will likely be the last to run unless you
 * have another plugin somewhere with a higher (>99) priority.
 */
add_filter( 'template_include', 'set_templates', 99 );

/**
 * Maybe set a template if we're on certain pages.
 *
 * @param  string $template The template that WP is going to use.
 * @return string A template file path
 */
function set_templates( $template ) {

    // Initialize the $new_template variable to an empty string.
    $new_template = '';

    // is_page will return "true" if the passed parameter matches the current page query.
    if ( is_page( 'example_1' )  ) {
        // If we match the query for 'example_1', for example, then we set the
        // new template path to the value of locate_template.
        $new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-1.php' ) );
    } elseif ( is_page( 'example_2' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-2.php' ) );
    } elseif ( is_single( 'example_3' )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( 'templates/example-3.php' ) );
    }

    // If we get a value for the new template, stop here and return it.
    if ( '' !== $new_template ) {
        return $new_template ;
    }

    // Otherwise, return the original template.
    return $template;
}
```

There's an important difference in my code and your original code, and that would be that we're setting up `$new_template = ''` at the beginning of the function, and the check against empty string was changed from a loose comparison `!=` to a strict comparison `!==`.

The reason for this is that the loose comparison was essentially allowing you to do something that relies on PHP just kind of "winging it". Beforehand, say you never hit one of the `locate_template` blocks - `$new_template` *would never get defined*. A loose check against undefined and empty string will work, but it may also raise some issues with PHP:

```
php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump($not_defined == '');
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: not_real in php shell code on line 1
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() php shell code:0

Notice: Undefined variable: not_real in php shell code on line 1

Call Stack:
    7.2574     352080   1. {main}() php shell code:0

php shell code:1:
bool(true)
php >
```

As you can see, `$not_defined` is loosely equal to empty string `''`, however PHP threw a `Notice` because `$not_defined` was never defined. In your case, setting `$new_template` to empty string first avoids any PHP complaints, and since `locate_template` either returns a string of the path to the template or an empty string `''`, we can use a strict comparison at the end.

To answer your question about what that comparison is doing, `$new_template !== ''` is saying "if we have a value for `$new_template` that is a string that isn't empty, return that." Otherwise, the control flow will pass over the `if` statement block and return the original `$template` WordPress was planning to use in the first place.

#### Further Reading

- Actions and Filters - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Hooks:_Actions_and_Filters
- `add_filter` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/
- `is_page` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/
- `locate_template` - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/

#### Alternatives (Update)

I just thought I would mention also that you can achieve a similar goal if you're willing to change your file structure a little. WordPress will look for PHP files matching a Page slug if the have a filename matching the format "page-.php", so in your example you could have this structure:

```
> ls wp-content
  ... // Other files
  page-example-1.php
  page-example-2.php
  page-example-3.php
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation. (And I'm sorry for my slow response.)